# Changing ylim's of subplotted graphs

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I subplotted the graphs using command `subplot(1,2,1)` and `subplot(1,2,2)`.I plotted the data. As you see I have 2 graphs in the figure.

I want to change y axis's border of the two graphs.

For example, I have `ylim=[0 0.5]` for the first graph and `ylim=[0 1.5]` for the second graph. I want to change these ylim's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get access to your figure :

```
Myfig=gcf; %If the figure you want to modify is the current figure
Myfig=figure(1); %Replace 1 by the number of your figure, this command will make figure(1) your current figure and return its handle in Myfig.
```

Now your subplots are stored in the 'Children' field of your figure. In this case, it will be a cell array containing two axes objects representing your subplots.

```
%If you don't have legends
Allsubplots=get(Myfig,'children'); 

% If you have legends, they will also appear as children of your fig
% Meaning you have to seek all fig's children that are of type 'axes'
Allsubplots=findobj(Myfig,'type','axes');

MySubplot1=Allsubplots(1);
MySubplot2=Allsubplots(2);

%%Change ylims of first subplot to [Ymin1 Ymax1] :
set(MySubplot1,'ylim',[Ymin1 Ymax1]);

%%Same for second subplot :
set(MySubplot2,'ylim',[Ymin2 Ymax2]);
```

**UPDATE :** If you already know *a priori* which subplot you want to change and how **AND** the figure you want to modify is your current figure :

```
MySubplot1=subplot(1,2,1);
MySubplot2=subplot(1,2,2);

%%Change ylims of first subplot to [Ymin1 Ymax1] :
set(MySubplot1,'ylim',[Ymin1 Ymax1]);

%%Same for second subplot :
set(MySubplot2,'ylim',[Ymin2 Ymax2]);
```

Comment: Thanks but it works for the second graph, not for the first.

Comment: I have 4x1 double. I have legends in the plots. May it be the problem?

Comment: I have legends in the plots. May it be the problem?

Comment: Yes it is (Although you still shouldn't have doubles, anyways, i'm editing my answer)

Comment: I want to do this  without plotting the data again. If I use subplot, I must plot the data again.

Comment: the line `MySubplot1=subplot(1,2,1);` just returns a handles to the subplot(1,2,1). EXACTLY the same as seeking a handle another way. Note that there is no call to `plot` in this piece of code.

Comment: @BillBookey thanks for your answer. Allsubplots=findobj(Myfig,'type','axes'); didn't give the true result. obtained the true result with this code.                                                                                              Allsubplots= findobj(gcf,'type','axes','-not','Tag','legend','-not','Tag','Colorbar');                                                  MySubplot1=Allsubplots(1);
MySubplot2=Allsubplots(2);
set(Mysubplot2,'ylim',[0 1]);
set(Mysubplot1,'ylim',[0 0.2]);

Comment: @BillBokeey `findobj(gcf,'type','axes');` should return `double` depending on your version of Matlab.